# How to move subsite from staging to production?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm working on SP 2013 environment...and customize some of the page using SharePoint designer. And upload it to the staging.

I would like to publish it to the production. It is subsite of the main site/Team Site

Comment: Only configuration or with development? First time or upgrade?

Comment: not upgrading or no configuration.

Comment: Add to your question please what kind of configuration did you do

Comment: @jpussacq I didn't say any configeration. I'm working on SP 2013environment...and customize some of the page using sharepoint designer. And upload it to the staging.  My client agreed on what I accomplish and would like to publish it to the production. It is sub site of the main site/Team Site

Comment: Depends a lot on what configuration, which method to use. You can save site as template and then create a site in production based on this template

Comment: I would recommend using tools like Sharegate or Metalogix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, you should use [`Import-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)/[`Export-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  Cmdlets to can move subsite.

**Export-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"
```

**Import-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

**Note:**

- Make sure that the source subsite is idintical to the destination sub-site. in case it's not identical so the best way to move your pages customizations manually. (You should think about identicality  in the future by reverse the export and import from production to staging )
- **Save site as template** is an option but it requires to create a new site not to overwrite the current site.